# Asymptotics of 2D Ising model transfer matrix eigenvalues

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, asymptotics

The NN 2D Ising Model at inverse temperature $\beta$ and external magnetic field $h$ on an $L_1\times L_2$ sized box within $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with periodic boundary conditions $$\sigma_{L_{1}+1,x_{2}} = \sigma_{1,x_{2}}\qquad\left(x_{2}=1,\dots,L_{2}\right)$$
$$\sigma_{x_{1},L_{2}+1} = \sigma_{x_{1},1}\qquad\left(x_{1}=1,\dots,L_{1}\right)$$ has Gibbs factor $$ \exp\left(\beta\sum_{x_1 = 1}^{L_1}\sum_{x_2=1}^{L_2}\left(\sigma_{x_1,x_2}\sigma_{x_1+1,x_2}+\sigma_{x_1,x_2}\sigma_{x_1,x_2+1}+h\sigma_{x_1,x_2}\right)\right) $$ and transfer matrix of dimensions $2^{L_2}\times 2^{L_2}$ given by
$$ T\left(\eta,\tilde{\eta}\right)=\exp\left(\beta\left\langle \eta,\tilde{\eta}\right\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\beta\left(V\left(\eta\right)+V\left(\tilde{\eta}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\beta h\left\langle 1,\eta+\tilde{\eta}\right\rangle \right)\qquad\left(\eta,\tilde{\eta}\in\{\pm1\}^{L_{2}}\right) $$ with $$ V\left(\eta\right)=\sum_{x_{2}=1}^{L_{2}}\eta_{x_{2}}\eta_{x_{2}+1} $$ and $\langle a,b\rangle \equiv \sum_{x_2=1}^{L_2} a_{x_2} b_{x_2} $ the inner product.

Question 1: Is this the best form for the transfer matrix or is there some kind of transformation to bring it into a more convenient form? E.g. if $h\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ then as far as I can see, $T$ is not Hermitian.

Question 2: I know that the 2D Ising model has an exact solution (although not at $h\neq0$ AFAIK). Can anyone point me to the literature on asymptotics of top eigenvalues $|\lambda_1|\geq |\lambda_2|\cdots$ of the transfer matrix as $L_1=L_2\to\infty$? In particular, asymptotics of $|\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}|$ as $j\to\infty$ which are uniform in $L_2$?